# How to duplicate/copy an item from one list onto another list

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm wondering how to copy one specific list and add it onto multiple UL's.  I'm trying to make it so that when the user clicks a button, it will add the task to both List 1 and List 2.

```
window.onload=function() {
  el = document.createElement('li');
  el.setAttribute("list2UL", "List2UL");
}

$(() => {
  $('input').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      const newList1 = $(this).val();
      if (newList1) {
        var li = $("<li><input type='checkbox' id='newlist1item' class='right-margin' <label>" + newList1 + "</label> <button type="button" class="deletelist"> </button> <button type="button" class="addtolist2"></button></li>");
        $('#tasksUL').append(li);
        $('#tasksUL').append(el);
        $(this).val("");
      }
    }
  });
  $(document).on("click", ".deletelist", function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });
});

      <label for="list1menu">
        <input type="text" name="newlist1" value="" spellcheck="false" placeholder="New List" id="newlist1">
        <ul id="list1UL">
          <li><input type="checkbox" id="newlist1item" class="right-margin"><label>List1</label> <button type="button" class="deletelist"> </button> <button type="button" class="addtolist2"></button></li>
        </ul>
      </label>

    <label for="list2 menu">
      <ul id="list2UL" class='list2UL'>
        <li><input type="checkbox" id="newlist2item" class="right-margin"><label>List2</label> <button type="button" class="deletelist"></button></li>
      </ul>
    </label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution for your question : https://jsfiddle.net/t09e8326/2/

You made many mistake in your code, such as you were not appending to the second list. Trying to append **el** element which is out of global scope.

HTML:

```
  <label for="list1menu">
    <input type="text" name="newlist1" value="" spellcheck="false" placeholder="New List" id="newlist1">
    <ul id="list1UL">
      <li><input type="checkbox" id="newlist1item" class="right-margin"><label>List1</label> <button type="button" class="deletelist"> Delete</button> <button type="button" class="addtolist2">Add to List2</button></li>
    </ul>
  </label>

<label for="list2 menu">
  <ul id="list2UL" class='list2UL'>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="newlist2item" class="right-margin"><label>List2</label> <button type="button" class="deletelist">Delete</button></li>
  </ul>
</label>
```

Script:

```
  $(() => {
      $('#newlist1').on('keypress', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
          const newList1 = $(this).val();
          if (newList1) {
            var li = "<li><input type='checkbox' id='newlist1item' class='right-margin' <label>" + newList1 + "</label> <button type='button' class='deletelist'> Delete</button> <button type='button' class='addtolist2'>Add to List 2</button></li>";
            $('#list1UL').append(li);
            $('#list2UL').append(li);
            $(this).val("");
          }
        }
      });
      $(document).on("click", ".deletelist", function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
      });
    });
```